# How to keep a structure from being destroyed?

Tags: c

I'm in desperate need of help. I've been working on this for over 20 hour. Basically I was able to scan the information into structures but it gets destroyed after the function finish. I need it to go to main. How can I do this?

```
struct tracks_{
  char *tracks_title;
  int playlist_hits;
};

struct album_ {
  int num_tracks;
  int *tracks;
};

typedef struct album_ album;
typedef struct tracks_ tracks;

album *pharse_album(FILE *album_file,int *number_of_albums){

  int number_of_album,number_of_tracks,number_of_charaters;
  int i,j;

  /*Gets the first number, which tell me how much albums there are*/
  fscanf(album_file,"%d", &number_of_album);

  album *all_albums_p = (album *)malloc(sizeof(album)*number_of_album);

  for(j=0;j<number_of_album;j++){
    for(i=0;i<all_albums_p[j].num_tracks;i++){
        /*This number tell me how many characters there are*/
        fscanf(album_file,"%d", &number_of_charaters);

        /*allocates memory*/
        all_albums_p[j].tracks = (int *)calloc(all_albums_p[j].num_tracks,sizeof(int));
        all_albums_p[j].tracks[i] = (char *)calloc(number_of_charaters+6,sizeof(char));


        fscanf(album_file, "%[^\n]s", all_albums_p[j].tracks[i]);

        /*Prints the tracks perfectly*/
        printf("%s\n",all_albums_p[j].tracks[i]);

        /*Sets playlist_hits 0*/
        all_tracks_p[i].playlist_hits = 0;
    }
  }
    return all_albums_p;
}

main(){
  int *number_of_albums,a;

  album *all_tracks_ptr;

  all_tracks_ptr = pharse_album(album_file,number_of_albums);

  int number_of_tracks[*number_of_albums];

    for(i=0; i < *number_of_albums ;i++){
      printf("%d : %d\n",i,all_tracks_ptr[i].num_tracks);

      /*Where the errors falls*/
      printf("%s",all_tracks_ptr[1].tracks[1]);

    }


    transaction(transaction_file);
  }
}
```

Comment: does it work if you print everything at the bottom of the `pharse_album()` method?

Comment: `album.tracks` is defined as `int *` (to be used as an array of `int`).  But you're putting `char *` into the array elements.  That's not the problem you're asking about but it indicates there are other problems in the code you need to deal with.

Comment: @twain249 no if I print it outside the loop it wont work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`all_albums_p[j].tracks = (int *)calloc(all_albums_p[j].num_tracks,sizeof(int));`

this gets executed on every iteration of `i`, allocating new memory and leaking the old one along with its stored data. You have to move this out from the inner loop.

The other major problem is that you don't return the number of albums, eg:

```
*number_of_albums = number_of_album;
```

Comment: Fixed this, thanks. But my main concern is getting this outside the pharse_album() function. The structures are getting destroyed before the pharse_album() function even ends.

Comment: you destroyed them by overwriting the pointers within the function. also, see update

Comment: I returned the numbers just forgot to copy that part =)

Comment: Thank you!!! You have no idea how much I appreciate your help! I spent well over 20 hours on this... I'm crying on the inside... Thank you so much!